# Send radio button value using Ajax Script in

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to send the `radio` button value to Controller via ajax request, and so far nothing works

```html
<input class="form-check-input" type="radio" class="gender" name="gender" id="Female" value="Female">
<label class="form-check-label" for="Female">Female</label><br>

<input class="form-check-input" type="radio" class="gender" name="gender" id="Male" value="Male">
<label class="form-check-label" for="Male"> Male </label><br>

<input class="form-check-input " type="radio" class="gender" name="gender" id="Other" value="Other">
<label class="form-check-label" for="Other">Other</label><br>
```

I tried with the following methods that do not work for me:

```
$('.gender:checked').val();

$('input[name="gender"]:selected').val();

$('#gender').val();
```

Any help?

Comment: The first method, `$('.gender:checked').val()`, works correctly. The issue in your code is that you've put two `class` attributes on the `input` elements, and the second one will be ignored. You need to fix that. The second method will also work if you change `:selected` to `:checked`. Voting to close as a typographical error.

Answer (score 0):

You should be responding to an event for example a click or an onchange event see more here:

```html
<input class="form-check-input" type="radio" class="gender" name="gender" id="Female" value="Female" />
<label class="form-check-label" for="Female">Female</label><br>

<input class="form-check-input" type="radio" class="gender" name="gender" id="Male" value="Male" />
<label class="form-check-label" for="Male"> Male </label><br>

<input class="form-check-input " type="radio" class="gender" name="gender" id="Other" value="Other" />
<label class="form-check-label" for="Other">Other</label><br>
```

```js
$("input[type='radio']").click((ev) => {
    console.log("click",ev.currentTarget.attributes.value.value);
})
$("input[type='radio']").change((ev) => {
    console.log("change",ev.target.attributes.value.value);
})
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g6d7mqev/1/)

Comment: 'You should be responding to an event' Why? What if the OP is validly trying to read the value selected on the server side when the page loads? Secondly, use `ev.target.value`, not the attributes collection.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan  **What if the OP is validly trying to read the value selected on the server side when the page loads?** ->What does this mean?

Answer (score 0):

In order to identidy the value of each field, use #id instead of .ClassName,

```
    $('#Female:checked').val();
    $('#Male').val();
    $('#Other').val();
```

otherwise, you can use radio buttons

Comment: No, don't do this. It's not extensible and will cause maintenance issues. Use classes properly.